# How to ensure the checksum of the dlls build from the same project are the same

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, compilation, linker

I am working on a project that need 3rd party company to verify our source code and we must insure that the dlls build at our site has the same checksum as the ones build at their site.

I am trying to setup the machine for them to build our project. the problem is that some of the dlls they build is different from the one we build.
  We are using visual studio 2005 to compile the project.
  Both machines are running windows XP prof SP3.
  The directory structures for both machines are the same.
  The source code and the project settings of the dlls are the same.
  And we did have a program to update the time stamp in the file header.

I used a tool call PE explorer to compare the dll files that are different, the difference is that in side the .text raw data segment, there are some of the mov functions reference to different address in the .data segment (initialized data). But the address they referenced to are all zero values which won't affect the .data segment or the functionality of the dll.

I just wanna know that whether there are any configurations inside visual studio or the windows XP that will cause this different?

Thanks